# How to avoid selecting input elements before they are made?

Tags: javascript, input, addeventlistener

The block of code that's causing me trouble is this:

```
btn.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
  if (!gamePlay) {
    gamePlay=true
    btn.innerHTML="Check Combo"
    makeGame(6)
  } else { 
    const inputs=Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('input'))
    for (let i=0; i<inputs.length; i++) {
      if (inputs[i].value!==inputs[i].correct) {
        instructions.innerHTML=`Guesses ${++guesses}`
        console.log(inputs[i].value)
        return
      } else {
        instructions.innerHTML=`It took you ${guesses} to win`
      }
    }
  }
})
```

It's clearly selecting the input elements before the user has changed the values of any. How do I restructure the code so that the program captures the input elements after the user has changed number values? I think it's because I placed this block of code too early.

As a result, even if the user gets the combination right, the input values are all empty so you'll never get to the else block.

Can anyone explain whats happening and how to fix this?

Comment: You need an event listener on the input fields to know when they change.

Comment: what is the rule of the game? what is the intention?

Comment: Do you want the colours to only show up when the button is pressed? You should move the code that sets them into the button’s `click` listener, then, instead of updating on `change`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It's clearly selecting the input elements before the user has changed the values of any.

This isn’t true, but it wouldn’t matter if it were. The only important thing is that they *exist* when they’re selected, which they do.

> As a result, even if the user gets the combination right, the input values are all empty

You’re logging the values to the console with `console.log(inputs[i].value)`. They aren’t empty, right?

The real issue is that the `correct` property is a number:

```
el.correct=Math.floor(Math.random()*5)+1
```

and the `value` property you’re comparing it to:

```
if (inputs[i].value!==inputs[i].correct) {
```

is a string. `!==` requires its operands to have the same type. Convert the value to a number to compare it:

```
if (Number(inputs[i].value) !== inputs[i].correct) {
```

[updated jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xw8jsteq/1/)